# How do I load rvm automatically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

Every time I load a new terminal I need to run this:

```
    source /usr/share/rvm/scripts/rvm
```

to load rvm

What do I have to do so that I don't have to run the command every time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On *linux*, or *mac* put it to the **.bashrc**:

```
echo "source /usr/share/rvm/scripts/rvm" >> ~/.bashrc
```

On *windows* you preuse `cygwin`, and do the same thing inside its terminal.

In case you are using `zsh` do it for its config **.zshrc**:

```
echo "source /usr/share/rvm/scripts/rvm" >> ~/.zshrc
```